# Searching for a specific word in JavaScript without using includes() method

Tags: javascript

I am required to find for a specific word in a text input whereby the word is the "+" symbol. The users for my program uses IE8 and IE11 and unfortunately when I looked in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_includes.asp), I found out that the includes() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 11 (or earlier). Below is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="recycle" name="txtEXT_AK" id="txtEXT_AK" size="10" onclick="this.select()">

document.getElementsByClassName("recycle").onkeyup = function(){checker()}

function checker(){
    var text_value=document.getElementsByClassName("recycle");
    word="+";
    
    var textValue = text_value.value;
    
    if (textValue.includes(word))
    {
      alert('found')
    }   
}
```

So far, there is no alert() coming out when I tried to enter the "+" symbol into the text box. Is there any alternative for the includes() method that I can use for the checker code? I have tried *indexOf*, *contains* and *match* but so far there is no luck. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You can use `indexOf`. What was your attempt that failed? It should be `textValue.indexOf(word) > -1`

Comment: You can use `match`

    if (textValue.match(/\+/)) {
        alert('found')
    }

Comment: FYI, IE ended support in June 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Actually，the key bug is not `"includes"`, you should change `getElementsByClassName('recycle')` to `getElementById('txtEXT_AK')`